# Can't finish transferring a file when using a multi-threaded server in C

Tags: c, multithreading, file, pthreads

I have a multi-threaded client that can transfer a batch of files to a new directory that the client itself makes. My client used to use a single-threaded server.

For an assignment I'm supposed to transform my single-threaded server into a multi-threaded server that creates a new thread for each client request. I'm also supposed to time the whole operation and output it to the client (which I got to work when the server was single threaded). The code for both the multi-threaded client (which works with a single-thread server) and the multi-thread server (which does not work well) are below:

client.c

```
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "Timer.h"

#define N_THREADS 10

char * files[] = {
    "/usr/share/dict/words",
    "/usr/include/sqlite3.h",
    "/usr/include/tclDecls.h",
    "/usr/include/bfd.h",
    "/usr/include/libmng.h",
    "/usr/include/elf.h",
    "/usr/include/gmpxx.h",
    "/usr/include/tkDecls.h",
    "/usr/include/H5overflow.h",
    "/usr/include/tcl.h",
    "/usr/include/gmp-x86_64.h",
    "/usr/include/curses.h",
    "/usr/include/lcms.h",
    "/usr/include/netapi.h",
    "/usr/include/gcrypt.h",
    "/usr/include/zlib.h",
    "/usr/include/ldap.h",
    "/usr/include/geos_c.h",
    "/usr/include/kdb.h",
    "/usr/include/tk.h",
    "/usr/include/yaml.h"
};

#define files_length() (sizeof files / sizeof files[0])

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(-1);
}

struct sockaddr_in make_server_addr(char *host, short port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof addr);
    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if ( hp == 0 )
        error(host);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr_list[0], &addr.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    return addr;
}

int connect_socket(char *host, short port)
{
    int status;
    int tries = 3;
    struct sockaddr_in addr = make_server_addr(host, port);
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( s == -1 )
        error("socket()");
    status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof addr);
    if ( status < 0 )
        error("connect refused");
    return s;
}

void request_file_from_server(int server_socket, char *file)
{
    int len = strlen(file);
    int n = write(server_socket, file, len);
    if ( n != len )
        error("short write");
}

void read_file_from_server(int server_socket, char *file)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n;
    mode_t mode = 0666;
    int ofd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode);
    if ( ofd == -1 )
        perror("open()");
    while ( (n = read(server_socket, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0 )
        write(ofd, buf, n);
    close(ofd);
}


struct Thread_data
{
    int id;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    char * host;
    short port;
    char path[BUFSIZ];
};

void make_file_name(char *local_name, char *dir, char *original_path)
{
    char *p = rindex(original_path, '/');
    if ( !p )
        error("rindex()");
    sprintf(local_name, "%s/%s", dir, p+1);
}

int remote_copy(struct Thread_data * data, char * file)
{
    int server_socket = connect_socket(data->host, data->port);
    request_file_from_server(server_socket, file);
    char local_name[BUFSIZ];
    make_file_name(local_name, data->path, file);
    read_file_from_server(server_socket, local_name);
    close(server_socket);
}

void make_empty_dir_for_copies(struct Thread_data * data)
{
    mode_t mode = 0777;
    sprintf(data->path, "./Thread_%d", (data->id + 1));
    mkdir(data->path, mode);
}

#define N_FILES_TO_COPY files_length() // copy them all

void *thread_work(void *arg)
{
    struct Thread_data * data = (struct Thread_data *)arg;
    make_empty_dir_for_copies(data);
    for ( int i=0; i < N_FILES_TO_COPY; ++i )
        remote_copy(data, files[i]);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void start_threads(char *host, short port, struct Thread_data thread_args[])
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; ++i )
    {
        struct Thread_data * t = &thread_args[i];
        t->id = i;
        t->host = host;
        t->port = port;
        pthread_create(&t->thread_id, NULL, thread_work, t);
    }
}

void join_threads(struct Thread_data thread_args[], double *eTime)
{
    for ( int i=0; i < N_THREADS; i++ )
        pthread_join(thread_args[i].thread_id, NULL);
    Timer_elapsedUserTime(eTime);
    printf("Elapsed time for transferring all files: %lf\n", *eTime);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct Thread_data thread_args[N_THREADS];
    char *host = argv[1];
    short port = atoi(argv[2]);
    double eTime;
    Timer_start();
    start_threads(host,port,thread_args);
    join_threads(thread_args, &eTime);

}
```

server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Timer.h"

#define BACKLOG 200
// more than this in the queue, and client connect will fail
#define NUM_THREADS 200


void error(char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(-1);
}


struct sockaddr_in make_server_addr(short port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    return addr;
}

int create_server_socket(short port)
{
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr = make_server_addr(port);
    if ( s == -1 )
        error("socket()");
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof my_addr);
    listen(s, BACKLOG);
    return s;
}

void get_file_request(int socket, char *fileName)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n = read(socket, buf, BUFSIZ);
    if ( n < 0 )
        error("read from socket");
    buf[n] = '\0';
    strcpy(fileName, buf);
    printf("Server got file name of '%s'\n", fileName);
}

void write_file_to_client_socket(char *file, int socket)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n;
    int ifd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    if ( ifd == -1 )
        error("open()");
    while ( (n = read(ifd, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0 )
        write(socket, buf, n);
    close(ifd);
}

void * handle_request(void * c_socket)
{
    int *client_socket = (int*)c_socket;
    char fileName[BUFSIZ];
    get_file_request(*client_socket, fileName);
    write_file_to_client_socket(fileName, *client_socket);
    close(*client_socket);
    pthread_exit(0);
    return NULL;
}

void time_out(int arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,  "Server timed out\n");
    exit(0);
}

void set_time_out(int seconds)
{
    struct itimerval value = {0};
    // bzero(&value, sizeof value);
    /* timerclear(&value.it_interval); timerclear(&value.it_value); */
    value.it_value.tv_sec = seconds;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &value, NULL);
    signal(SIGALRM, time_out);
}

void accept_client_requests(int server_socket)
{
    pthread_t threads;
    int client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof client_addr;
    set_time_out(10);
    while ( (client_socket =
            accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &sin_size)) )
    {
        set_time_out(10);
        pthread_create(&threads,0, handle_request,&client_socket);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
        error("usage: server port");
    short port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int server_socket = create_server_socket(port);
    accept_client_requests(server_socket);
    shutdown(server_socket, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue happens when using `handle_request` when I am using `accept` and creating a new `pthread`. It gets to whatever the last file is (in this case `/usr/include/yaml.h`), hangs and then times out. Without a timeout it would hang indefinitely.

I don't really know much about multi-threading with pthreads, so I'm just going off of my professors instructions which basically said to create the thread and handle the request like you would in a single threaded server. In my single threaded server, `handle_request` was passed in an int (which now gets converted).

Does anyone know why my server would hang on the last transferred file until it times out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw in the `accept_client_requests` function. You have a variable

```
int client_socket;
```

The address of that variable is passed to `pthread_create`

```
pthread_create(&threads,0, handle_request,&client_socket);
```

`pthread_create` passes the pointer to `handle_request` which stores it as a local pointer

```
int *client_socket = (int *)c_socket;
```

The problem is that the pointer is still pointing to the `client_socket` variable in the `accept_client_requests` function.  So when `accept_client_requests` gets another connection, the `client_socket` is changed, and every thread currently running has its `client_socket` changed, which should cause all sorts of chaos.

The solution is to `malloc` an `int` to hold the `client_socket`, and then pass that address to the thread.

```
int *temp = malloc( sizeof(int) );
*temp = client_socket;
pthread_create(&threads, 0, handle_request, temp);
pthread_detach(threads);
```

When the thread is finished, it should `free` the memory.

---

The `accept_client_requests` function should also call `pthread_detach` on every thread that it creates, so that resources can be reclaimed when the thread finishes.

Without the `pthread_detach` the system will expect to see a `pthread_join` before cleaning up the thread.

Comment: That does make sense, and it gets past the problem I was having trying to figure out how to not just pass a pointer into the handle_requests function. But when I try this solution (and free memory outside of the while loop in handle_requests), it only creates a few directories with only a single file in them, and gives me a bunch of connection refused error messages before crashing.

Comment: @Alex, I forgot to mention `pthread_detach`, updated the answer.

Comment: pthread_detach(pthread_self()); after using pthread_create does create the 10 directories, but it seems to only copy one file name, without anything in it, and states that the connection is refused. Am I supposed to use pthread_detach in the handle request?

Comment: @Alex I would put the `pthread_detach` right after the `pthread_create` (see updated answer). Note the `pthread_detach` simply tells the OS that you aren't going to call `pthread_join` on that thread, so the OS can clean up immediately when the thread is done.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, I'm actually learning quite a bit about this stuff now. However running server and then client gives me this: for server: `read from socket, read from socket, read from socket`, and from client: `Connection refused`. It still doesn't seem to want to copy over enough directories, and is still copying over only one file. :((

Comment: @Alex, Yup, fix one bug, uncover three more :) That's the way it goes sometimes. I suggest limiting the client to 1 thread and reduce the file list to two files. You may be running into resource limits, e.g. maximum number of sockets, threads, open files, etc. Or there could be some bugs that I didn't see while reviewing the code.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'll try to limit the threads / files to debug the code. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex Any time, glad to help :)